# Example of time function that doesn't have an average (theta) bound

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I understand that, given a time function `T(n)`, `O(g(n))` means that `g(n)` is an upper bound of `T(n)`, `omega(g(n))` means that `g(n)` is a lower bound and `theta(g(n))` means that `g(n)` is both.

For example if `T(n) = 2n+1`, then it is `theta(n)` since `2n+1 <= 3n` for `n >= 1` and `2n+1 >= n` for `n>=1`. Or for instance, the function `T(n) = n^2 logn + n` is `theta(n^2 logn)` since `n^2 logn <= n^2 logn + n <= 10n^2 logn`.

However, I can't think of a `T(n)` for which we can't find a theta bound. Can someone, please, give me one or two examples of a case where we cannot find a function `g(n)` such that `T(n) = theta(g(n))` for, if they exist of course?

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

EDIT: I'd like to mention that I am not looking for trivial cases. For example it is obvious that for any `T` we can say that `T(n) = Theta(T)`.

The other "trivial" case `T(n) = Theta(c*T(n) + d)` probably answers my question, since `g(n)=c*T(n) + d` is indeed a new function different from `T(n)`.

Comment: I don't know if there's a mathematical function with that property (I would think not, at least not based on the standard building blocks of complexity analysis like `n^3`, `log(n)`, `sqrt(n)`, `2^n`). But there are algorithms whose time complexity cannot be expressed as a theta bound. For example, quick sort has average running time that is O(n logn), but worst case O(n^2). So there is no `g(n)` such that the running time of quick sort is `theta(g(n))`.

Comment: I mean, `T(n)` is `Theta(T(n))`...

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks. Correct me if im wrong but cant we, for the average running time, say thats its `Theta(nlogn)` and for the worst time, `O(n^2)` ?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks, I m aware of this. But my question/thought is more about if we can find another g(n). Well you can always say to me that g(n) = T(n) + constant, so yeah I guess your argument is valid.

Comment: @Thomas The more interesting question is whether there is one that doesn't have a "nice" Theta bound.  And the answer to that is yes.  For example consider an algorithm that tries to find the last power of 2 by going back number by number until it finds one that trial division says is a power of 2.  If you pass it a power of 2, it takes `Theta(log(n))` time.  If you pass it in one less than a power of 2, it takes `Theta(n)` time.  The function itself is a crazy sawtooth that bounces between those two extremes.

Comment: @btilly Good example. But still, in each of these cases, there is a `Theta bound` for the `T(n)`, isn't there?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, and trivially so.  The only question is whether the available Thetas form a nice hierarchy.  They don't.

Comment: @btilly I see. Thank you for the answers :)

Answer (score 2):

The Theta notation does not give an average bound on a function, it specifies a lower and upper bound (up to constant factors) on a function.

The answer to your question is no. There is no time function `T` such for any function `g`, `T` is not in `Theta(g)`, because trivially `T` is an element of `Theta(T)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im aware of the trivial case where `T = Theta(T)`. I was wondering about another function than `T`.

Comment: I think your question is not well defined. For example, also trivially, `T(n) = Theta(c*T(n) + d)` for all `T`, `c` and `d`.

Comment: You are correct, I wasn't very clear. I will edit the question, for anyone that might take a look at it sometime. However your second example, `T(n) = Theta(c*T(n) + d)` is closer to what I am asking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a function to be theta bound, we need to have Ω(g(n)) <= Θ(g(n)) <= O(g(n)). For people need to know further, there is an explanation here https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/aysmptotic-notations

For an f(n) = n! function, where n > 0, there can be only one lower bound found, which is 1!

ie., 1! <= n! But the problem here is we can't find a common g(n) here, such that C * g(n) is formed. Since there is no common g(n), a function of n here,
f(n) = n! can't be theta bound or tight bound.

NOTE: Here we can find a decent upper bound. Let's say,
10 * n! can be a Big-Oh, as 10 is C and n! is g(n). And this follows the principle C * g(n) >= f(n)